# Why can we create new instances of a generic template and not of generic type in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I'm aware that it's not possible to do:
`new T` where `T` is a generic type due to type erasure.

Why then is it okay to do something like `new A<T>` where T is generic? For example, why does the following compile?

```
static class A<T>{
    T t;
    A(T t){
        this.t=t;
    }
}

static class B<T>{

    A<T> create(T t){
        return new A<T>(t);
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    A<Integer> a = new B<Integer>().create(3);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because `A<Integer>` is a well defined type at compile and runtime.

At conceptual, intermediate step, after:

```
new B<Integer>()
```

your call to `.create(3)` is equivalent to calling:

```
static class B {
    A<Integer> create(Integer t){
        return new A<Integer>(t);
    }
}
```

after erasure, `A<Integer>` becomes `A`, which is a valid type.

You can't do `new T` because `T` is not a well defined type, it's just a token. If you really need, you can get the corresponding class and instantiate an object of type `T` using something like:

```
public class GenericFactory {
    <T> T create(Class<T> c) throws Exception {
        return c.newInstance();
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
new GenericFactory().create(Integer.class);
```

yes, that's ugly.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to type erasure that you can instantiate `new A<T>()`. If Java implemented Generics as reifiable, this would not work without reflection used to find out the runtime binding of `T`.

By extension, it is due to the fact that the non-generic aspect of object types is reified (accessible with `getClass()`), it is impossible to the compiler to emit such bytecode which would be able to instantiate any type T, depending on the call site.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating new instances of generic templates. You are creating instances of objects using generic templates.

```
new A<T>(t);
```

creates a new `A`, which is not generic. You do not necessarily know on compile time what will `T` be, but you know that the object will be an `A`. In fact the beauty in it is that you do not have to foretell what `T` will be, which allows you to create such powerful codes, which will be reusable. Imagine, if you implement a `Stack`, then you are not interested in what the actual content type will be. You are interested to handle well the `top`, `pop`, `push` operations. If you do not have to foretell whether the elements will be `Integer`, `String` or other types, you can elegantly write general codes applicable to many different classes.

If I had to foretell what `T` is, then I would rather say it is an `Object` and would be able to handle any objects then. I believe in fact something like this happens in the background. Also, another option would be to use `reflection`, but that would be not clean at all.